# servicestack angular 2 template on mac

Tags: angular, servicestack

is there any way to generate project without visual studio just on mac with rider or vs code?
Don't really want to install windows only for creating empty project to try real promising template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, the [Webpack SPA templates added in v4.5.10](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.10) are for ASP.NET v4.5, for non Windows platforms we recommend using .NET Core release of ServiceStack. We'll be working on developing SPA templates for .NET Core in this release, you can vote for this [feature request to get notified when SPA templates are available](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/17662525-servicestack-net-core-and-angular-2-template) for .NET Core.